# Storing content into a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

Currently I have created a custom taxonomy with the name "**genre**" and I am wondering how I can include it into the array for posting with the content from the string provided in the example.

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $post_title ) ),
  'post_content'  => $my_post,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 2,
  'post_category' => array( 2 ),
  'the_taxonomy' => $v['artist']['name'],
  'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

The custom taxnomy I am currently using can be seen below.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_genre_nonhierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

function create_topics_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {


$labels = array(
  'name' => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'singular_name' => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
  'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Genre' ),
  'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Genre' ),
  'all_items' => __( 'All Genre' ),
  'parent_item' => null,
  'parent_item_colon' => null,
  'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Genre' ), 
  'update_item' => __( 'Update Genre' ),
  'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Genre' ),
  'new_item_name' => __( 'New Genre Name' ),
  'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate topics with commas' ),
  'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove topics' ),
  'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used topics' ),
  'menu_name' => __( 'Genre' ),
); 

register_taxonomy('topics','post',array(
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true,
  'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
));
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: I do not know what you're asking. Could you explain in different terms what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You see where I have the taxonomy in the first portion? It's not displaying anything the Taxonomy's name is "Genre" how can I make it display the contents from the string provided.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. What is `$v`? Where is it being populated? `the_taxonomy` isn't a valid parameter to any post args I know of so I'm assuming this is just a custom array. Is `$v['artist']['name']` supposed to hold some kind of term content?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The content in that string is not important it just holds the artist name for that post, I am trying to figure out the way to put this into the array how ever.. I am sorry if I am being very confusing I'm trying to explain in the best way I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing but assuming that you want your array to be an argument set for, say, [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) then...

> I am wondering how I can include it into the array for posting with
>   the content from the string provided in the example.

... you need `tax_input`. I am pretty sure I've got this right:

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $post_title ) ),
  'post_content'  => $my_post,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 2,
  'post_category' => array( 2 ),
  'tax_input' => array(
    'genre' => 'abcdefg',
  ),
  'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```